# Is it posible to have a local state `isLoading` with Redux Toolkit Query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a list of components that all of them dispatch an action for a RTK Query. My question is if there is any form to have a `isLoading` from RTK Query local to the component instead of global. Or what is the best way to handle the local state?

Comment: I don't get it, you can access `isLoading` in a component https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#query-hook-usage-example

Comment: My suggestion is that the loading action must be local. You should not use loading globally.

Comment: @Konrad but I have a list of component that can trigger the query. Thus every component will show a loading state.

Comment: @HarshKukarwadiya I read about using useLazyQuery but im not sure if that is the best aproach

Comment: *I have a list of component that can trigger the query* - it sounds like each of these components need the response and should show that they are loading

Answer (score 0):

RTKQ cache entries are intentionally shared across any component that uses that query hook + cache key combination.  In other words, if I have 5 components that all call `useGetPokemonQuery('pikachu')`, all of them read the same cache entry object, and all have the same loading state.  The loading status is about the cache entry itself, not the component.

Comment: In this case I dont want cache. I want each of the components to dispatch an action individually like `addPokemonToCaughtList(pokemon)` and have a `isLoading` per component

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, tbh. Why would you want to re-fetch the _same_ data multiple times?